# I tried to type a function to add a node at the end of a singlylinked list but is doesn't work

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I typed the function to add the node at the end of a singly linked list.
But is doesn't work.

I have tried using if else to display 1st node,when list is empty(by condition head=NULL). Somehow it seems to work.

```
void insert(int x)
 {
    node* temp=new node;
    node* n=head;
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=NULL;

    while(n!=NULL)
    {
        n=n->next;
    }
    n->next=temp;
}
```

The program is showing segmentation fault.

Comment: Can this work in my case?

Comment: n->next=temp; can it work, it sets the link

Answer (score 4):

This just assigns your new node to a local variable `n`. It doesn't change a thing in your list:

```
n=temp;
```

An efficient way to do this would be something like this instead:

```
void insert(int x)
{
    node** pp = &head;
    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    *pp = new node;
    (*pp)->data = x;
    (*pp)->next = nullptr;
}
```

This simply walks the pointers *in* the list using a pointer-to-pointer. Upon finding the termination pointer (which may be `head` if the list is empty and the `head` value was `nullptr` in case that wasn't obvious), the new node is allocated and hung in place. This also fixes a problem in your original post (hanging the first node on an empty list with a null `head`).